# Phase shifted full bridge converter wrong output waveform

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply

I am trying to simulate a phase shifted full bridge converter in PSIM. However, the output waveforms are not satisfactory.

This is my model in PSIM:-[image]

For design calculations I have followed "Soft-switching PWM full-bridge converters" by Xinbo Ruan.

The output voltage waveform:
[image]

The voltage waveform is a bit sinusoidal instead of the general triangular shape. The output current waveform is scaled version of voltage waveform.
All waveforms are seemingly correct other than the output waveforms.

Voltmeter reading (waveform) after the diode rectifier:-
[image]

I don't understand how this turns into the above waveform after the LC filter. I have tried varying Lf but it didn't give any useful information, still the same shape of waveforms.

I have attached the simulation file and calculations for design below as google drive hyperlinks.

[Design Calculations](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y0a5yxJ0ziK2aVYVcRHIwYX-AS6r4cqT/view?usp=share_link)

[PSFB-psim file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j9Zwt7ghPA_3TKuiDrkWimT59HBaNWaa/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: You might want to refine TRTOL, RELTOL, MAXORD, etc. (or whatever the PSIM equivalents are) to make the "sine" a bit less jumpy (the line segments drawn between timesteps are evident). Given that the amplitude is tiny compared to the DC output, I would be inclined to leave it alone. But I don't know if you have further purposes in this direction.

Comment: In simpler terms, your plotting setup does not use enough data points, so you get more of a sharp edge waveform.  Do you know how to make those setup adjustments in the simulator? May be time to read more of the documentation and review circuit examples, app notes, etc.

Comment: So,  I have decreased the time steps and waveforms are not choppy anymore. However, the output waveforms are still sine-y compared to triangular shape waveforms in the textbook. Also, the elements are ideal, I can't still figure out the reason for the sinusoidal nature of these waveforms.

Comment: The output inductor and capacitor are probably playing a significant role in turning it into a sine shape. What text book circuit and waveforms are you comparing against?

Comment: Why don't you give a try to my free [ready-made](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) SIMPLIS templates which, for most of them, work on the free demo version. There are VM and CM versions of phase-shifted converters.

Comment: I have referred text book "Soft-Switching PWM Full-Bridge Converters: Topologies, Control, and Design" by Xinbo